# Quickblox does not receive Push Notifications

Tags: notifications, push, quickblox

I'm using Quickblox as chat platform provider.

As I followed the guide & sample from Quickblox. Whenever I sent message from Quickblox Admin Panel, I often got sent error with code: Invalid token (8).

Otherwise, If I sent notifications from an user on one phone to another user on their phone, most of time I got error, some (very little time) it report to Delivered. Whenever It's delivered, sometime the app received the notifications in about few hours, every thing work wells on that time. After that happy hours, it's not received anymore, I got stuck with them.

Although I subscribed, upload the .p12 key to admin panel in the right way. I think there is no mistake from my side, in my code and Quickblox configuration.

Below is the screenshot from Push Notification admin panel of Quickblox.

[image: Delivery with Failed]
[image: Delivery with Succeeded to one device, but the phone does not received]

The two above message are sent delay after each-other 10 seconds. NO change from source code and Admin in that period.

[image: Two message which are reported to sent, but one failed, another not]

What am i wrong? is Quickblox reliable? How about the failed rate? Why almost of the notifications failed to deliver? Why almost of the time the notifications did not come?

Comment: I have the same issue. How did you resolved the same.